# Use of @Remote(interface.class)

Tags: annotations, ejb

Does the use of @Remote(interface.class) in the ejb have any impact?

In other words. What's the diference between this:

```
@Remote(MyRemoteInterface.class)
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyRemoteInterface {
```

And this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyRemoteInterface {
```

When the inteface looks like this:

```
@Remote
public interface MyRemoteInterface {
```

Both solutions works fine on JBoss 6.4 when using the bean through the remote inteface.

Comment: The reason why ejb spec allows the definition of '@Local' and '@Remote' on the bean class is because in some cases you may not be in a position to annotate the interface(if you are not the one defining the interface - from third library for example ). In this case you may want to specify that the implemented interfaces are remote or local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, its just different way of writing it, see 2.1.2 of the EJB 3.1 spec:

> The interface can be annotated on with @Local or @Remote on the
>   interface class, or annotated with @Local (.class) or @Remote
>   (.class) on the bean class

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @maress said in his comment, there is other advantages / disadvantages for using  `@Local` and `@Remote` on the bean class, you can find a good summary [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/03/defining-ejb-3-1-views-local-remote-no-interface/).

I will quote the related parts regarding your question:

**Bean class with @Local / @Remote annotation:**

> ***Advantages:***
>
> - Information about interface type is loosely-coupled. You can ship your API to the client and don’t care about EJB semantics. If you’ll hide it with a facade your end-user (even a developer) doesn’t even have to know it’s using EJB technology under the hood.
> - Thanks to the Java implements clause you can use javac or your IDE to make sure all EJB business methods are implemented.
>
> ***Disadvantages:***
>
> - Your EJB must now define all its business interfaces using `@Local` annotation so it’s additional work for you. Not only you implement an
>     interface but you need to remember to declare that your EJB is
>     exposing it. There is nothing (from the javac perspective) preventing
>     you from putting an interface into `@Local` annotation that is not
>     actually implemented by your EJB.

**Interface with @Local / @Remote annotation:**

> ***Advantages:***
>
> - You don’t have to specify interface type in your EJB. You just “Java implement” it and the container do the rest.
> - Information about interface type is strongly attached to the interface so it might be easier to understand for other developers.
> - Thanks to the Java implements clause you can use javac or your IDE to make sure all EJB business methods are implemented.
>
> ***Disadvantages:***
>
> - Your interface now is tightly coupled with EJB technology (importing `javax.ejb.*` package.) You must now provide your API client
>     with required libraries to use it.